# Websphere 8.5 EJB lookup between different EARs on same Application Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

I've got a little Problem with my Websphere Application Server and the ejb remote lookup between two different EAR files on the same Server.

There is a main System (EAR File) from which I want to consume a Service of another System (EAR File). So I'am trying to use a remote lookup to get the Bean. But unfortunately I always receive a Exception that this Bean is not defined by the caller Bean:

Main-System: main_b.ear ---- Main-Bean: XMLSessionProxyBean

Metadata-System: metadata_b.ear ---- Metadata-Bean: MetadataServiceBean

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ejb/metadata_b/metadata-service.jar/MetadataServiceBean#de.metadata.service.MetadataServiceRemote was not defined for main_b#main-ejbs.jar#XMLSessionProxyBean
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.javaColonLookup(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:692)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanO.lookup(BeanO.java:1333)
```

Here is my lookup Method in the Main-System. Iam using the sessionContext (dont want to create a InitialContext since I'am already in a session):

```
private static String METADATA_BEAN_LOOKUP =
            "ejb/metadata_b/metadata-service.jar/MetadataServiceBean#de.metadata.service.MetadataServiceRemote";

public MetadataServiceRemote getMetadataService() {
        return getLocalEJB(METADATA_BEAN_LOOKUP);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T> T getLocalEJB(final String jndiName) {
        T localEjb = null;
        final SessionContext sContext = objContext.getSessionContext();
        localEjb = (T) sContext.lookup(jndiName);
        return localEjb;
    }
```

It's no Option for me to use injections like `@EJB` and also not to use local lookups with WAS shared libraries. I think I have to use ejb-jar.xml and ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml or something rather. At the moment there is no ejb-jar.xml or other deployment descriptors. So I just use default bindings.

Does anyone has a clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using the global namespace jndiname did the job:

java:global/metadata_b/metadata-service/MetadataServiceBean!de.metadata.service.MetadataServiceRemote

Answer (score 1):

Using the global namespace jndiname did the job: java:global/metadata_b/metadata-service/MetadataServiceBean!de.metadata.service.‌​MetadataServiceRemote

:-)

Comment: Indeed, by default EJBContext.lookup is relative to the java:comp/env namespace of the EJB, so unless you declare an EJB ref (e.g., `@EJB(name="ejb/metadata_b...")`), you'll need to use a java:global name.